# Linear gradient border bleeding

Tags: css, border, linear-gradients

I'm wonder if anyone have experienced border bleeding problem when using linear-gradient and border-radius. It also shows differently chrome, ie11, firefox and safari. Sometimes it is partly and sometimes it is like in the picture.
Expected behavour is no border line.
[image]

```
position: relative;    
text-align: center;
min-width: 6.59375rem;
min-height: 6.59375rem;    
width: 6.59375rem;  
height: 6.59375rem;    
border-radius: 50%;    
background-color: #00B7BD;
background-image: linear-gradient(202deg, transparent 50%, rgb(255, 255, 255) 50%), linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(255, 255, 255) 50%, transparent 50%);
```

Comment: Ok, now what is the problem here?

Comment: Well it's not suppose to have that tiny line as you can see. It is suppose to be white.